# Determine return type and parameter types of a lambda

Tags: c++

Given a lambda `[](int) -> float {...}`, how can one determine its return and parameter types without using std::function?

I've come with something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct function_traits;

template<typename R, typename ...Args>
struct function_traits<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    static const size_t nargs = sizeof...(Args);
    using result_type = R;

    template <size_t i>
    struct arg
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
    };
};

template<typename _Fn>
void foo(_Fn&&__callable)
{
    std::function fn(std::forward<_Fn>(__callable));
    using traits = function_traits<decltype(fn)>;
}
```

but I don't want to create `std::function` instance. Is there another way?

Comment: The obvious question is _why_ do you need this information?  What is it for, beyond trivia?  Or are you trying to allow/deny certain types of lambdas somewhere?

Comment: Why do you need to find those out? What problem is that supposed to solve? Please ask about that problem directly instead. If it's plain curiosity then that's fine, but please say so in your question.